# Python: to prolong elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a new list based on the old one, from ['a','b','c'] to ['a12', 'b12', 'c12'].

a classic way can be:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
aa = []

for item in a:
    aa.append(item + '12')

print aa
```

however I want to learn a better way so I tried:

```
aa = a.extend('12%s' % item for item in l[:])
```

and

```
aa = [item.join('12') for item in l]
```

but they don't produce the most correct one. what are the better ways?

thanks.

Comment: `item.join('12')` does something you don't want, please read the docs on `join` before using it. `a.extend` adds items to `a` and returns None.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aa = [item + '12' for item in a]`

Answer (score 1):

use `map` built-in function

```
a  = ['a','b','c']
aa = map(lambda x:x+"12",a)
print aa
>> ['a12', 'b12', 'c12']
```

Comment: `map` and `filter` in most cases are less Pythonic than list comprehensions

Comment: thanks, levi! 'lambda' probably is not a straight way for newbie like me. so hope you don't mind I don't choose yours the answer even yours is the earliest. :)

Comment: @MarkK yep no problem :), the good thing is you learned something new.